Closed form expression of 2D CFT integral
I am currently working on a 2d CFT and am wanting to compute a complex plane integral, making sure I take into consideration potential contact terms as well. The integral in question is
$$ \int_{\mathbb{C}} d^2z \frac{1}{|z - w_1|^{2\Delta_1}}\frac{1}{|z - w_2|^{2\Delta_2}} \tag{1}$$
where $|z - w_1|^2 = (z - w_1)(\bar{z} - \bar{w_1})$, $d^2z = 2  d \Re(z) d \Im(z)$, $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$ two complex numbers and $z, w_1$ and $w_2$ three points on the complex plane. By contact terms, I mean that I guess the end result should somehow split into a part proportional to $\delta^2(w_1 - w_2)$ and another bit which is not.
The only reference I could find that provides a hint at the answer is this one where they write in Eq (2.10)
$$
\int_{\mathbb{C}} d^2z \frac{1}{|z - w_1|^{2(1+i\lambda)}}\frac{1}{|z - w_2|^{2(1-i\lambda)}} = \frac{4\pi^2}{\lambda^2}\delta^2(w_1 -w_2)\tag{2.10}
$$
but I was unable to rederive it.

Can you explain the limit of the integral? It seems that it has to do with some definition of the delta function: https://books.physics.oregonstate.edu/LinAlg/deltareps.html .

It is integrated over the whole complex plane, here in particular the integration is defined as $ \int d^2z = 2 \int d \Re(z) d \Im(z) $ where the real and imaginary parts are integrated from minus to plus infinity.

Are there any restrictions on the complex weights $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$?

A priori no restrictions !


We identify OP's complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ with a $d=2$ real plane. Let us for fun generalize to $d$ spacetime dimensions. Let the total conformal weight be $\Delta:=\Delta_1+\Delta_2$. By translation and rotational symmetry, OP's integral can only depend on the distance square $w^2=w\cdot w$, where $w:=w_1-w_2$. OP's integral (1) becomes
$$ \begin{align}I(w)~=~&
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!d^dz
\frac{1}{(z-w_1)^{2\Delta_1}}
\frac{1}{(z-w_1)^{2\Delta_2}}\cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!d^dz
\frac{1}{(z-w)^{2\Delta_1}}
\frac{1}{z^{2\Delta_2}}\cr
~\stackrel{\text{Feyn.param.}}{=}~&
\frac{1}{B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!d^dz\int_{[0,1]}\!dx
\frac{x^{\Delta_1-1}(1-x)^{\Delta_2-1}}{
[x(z-w)^2+(1-x)z^2]^{\Delta}}\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!d^dz\int_{[0,1]}\!dx
\frac{x^{\Delta_1-1}(1-x)^{\Delta_2-1}}{
[z^2+x(1-x)w^2]^{\Delta}}\cr
~\stackrel{(14.27)}{=}~&
\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}
\frac{\Gamma(\Delta-\frac{d}{2})}{
\Gamma(\Delta)}
\int_{[0,1]}\!dx
\frac{x^{\Delta_1-1}(1-x)^{\Delta_2-1}}{
[x(1-x)w^2]^{\Delta-\frac{d}{2}}}\cr
~=~&\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{(w^2)^{\Delta-d/2}}
\frac{\Gamma(\Delta-\frac{d}{2})}{\Gamma(\Delta)}
\frac{B(\frac{d}{2}-\Delta_1,\frac{d}{2}-\Delta_2)}{
B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}\cr
~=~&\frac{C\pi^{d/2}}{(w^2)^{\Delta-d/2}}
\frac{\Gamma(\Delta-\frac{d}{2})}{\Gamma(d-\Delta)},
\end{align} \tag{A}$$
where the constant
$$ 
C~:=~\frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}-\Delta_1)
\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}-\Delta_2)}{\Gamma(\Delta_1)\Gamma(\Delta_2)}.\tag{B}$$

The Fourier transform of OP integral is
$$\begin{align}\widetilde{I}(k)
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!d^dw e^{-ik\cdot w}I(w)\cr
~=~&\ldots
~=~C\pi^d\left(\frac{4}{k^2}\right)^{d-\Delta}.
\end{align} \tag{C}$$

OP is interested in potential contact terms. If we count length-dimensions $[w]=1$, then $$[\partial_w^n\delta^d(w)]~=~-d-n.\tag{D}$$

Let us focus on a possible non-derivative Dirac delta distribution contact term. Then the total conformal weight $\Delta=d$ for dimensional reasons. In this case eq. (A) does not make sense due to the factor $\frac{1}{\Gamma(d-\Delta)}=0$. However the Fourier transform $\widetilde{I}(k)$ is $k$-independent/constant, so OP's integral is indeed a Dirac delta distribution:
$$ \Delta=d:\qquad I(w)~=~C\pi^d\delta^d(w).\tag{E}$$


References:

M. Srednicki, QFT, 2007; eq. (14.27). A prepublication draft PDF file is available here.


Thank you for this nice generalisation, which seems to make sense to me ! Just maybe one comment I guess if we use the convention that $d^2z=2d\Re z d\Im z$, we get an extra factor of $2^{d/2}$ in your equation (A) and a $2^d$ in your equation (C) and (E)?

The $z$ in the answer is assumed to be real.

Ok I see thanks

A very common integral which is almost enough to prove this is
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d^2 z}{|z - w_1|^{2\beta_1} |z - w_2|^{2\beta_2}} = \frac{\Gamma(\beta_1 + \beta_2 - 1)}{\Gamma(2 - \beta_1 - \beta_2)} \frac{\Gamma(1 - \beta_1) \Gamma(1 - \beta_2)}{\Gamma(\beta_1) \Gamma(\beta_2)} \frac{2\pi}{|w_{12}|^{2\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 - 2}}. \quad (1)
\end{equation}
If you haven't seen this before, it can be derived using the Feynman parameter method that Qmechanic is using (without the need for a regulator) or by writing down Symanzik's star integral and taking a limit similar to the one I will use below. Note that the factor of $2$ is a Jacobian because
\begin{equation}
d^2z = dz d\bar{z} = 2 d\Re(z) d\Im(z)
\end{equation}
as you say.
Anyway, step 1 is using (1) with $\beta_1, \beta_2$ equal to your $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$. Since $\Delta_1 + \Delta_2 = 2$, the argument of the first gamma function in the denominator goes to 0 and the integral vanishes except possibly when $w_1 = w_2$. So your integral $I(w_{12})$ is some multiple of $\delta^2(w_{12})$. Step 2 is now to show that the overall constant is $(2\pi / \lambda)^2$ by evaluating
\begin{equation}
\int d^2w_1 I(w_{12}) = \int d^2w I(w) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int d^2w I(w) \left | \frac{x}{x - w} \right |^{2\alpha}.
\end{equation}
The above expression is now
\begin{align}
\int d^2w_1 I(w_{12}) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int d^2w \int d^2z \frac{|x|^{2\alpha}}{|z|^{2\Delta_1} |w - z|^{2\Delta_2} |w - x|^{2\alpha}}
\end{align}
where we should do the $w$ integral first with (1). This leads to
\begin{align}
\int d^2w_1 I(w_{12}) &= 2\pi \lim_{x \to \infty} \int d^2z \frac{\Gamma(\Delta_2 + \alpha - 1)}{\Gamma(2 - \Delta_2 - \alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(1 - \Delta_2) \Gamma(1 - \alpha)}{\Gamma(\Delta_2) \Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{|x|^{2\alpha}}{|z|^{2\Delta_1} |z - x|^{2\Delta_2 + 2\alpha - 2}} \\
&= 4\pi^2 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(1 - \Delta_2) \Gamma(1 - \Delta_1)}{\Gamma(\Delta_2) \Gamma(\Delta_1)} \frac{\Gamma(1 - \alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(\Delta_1 + \Delta_2 + \alpha - 2)}{\Gamma(3 - \Delta_1 - \Delta_2 - \alpha)} |x|^{4 - 2\Delta_1 - 2\Delta_2}
\end{align}
where in the second line we have done the remaining $z$ integral with (1). Now since $\Delta_1 + \Delta_2 = 2$, this result is actually independent of $x$ and the limit can just be dropped. We also see that the last gamma ratio cancels the second last one so all we have is
\begin{align}
4\pi^2 \frac{\Gamma(1 - \Delta_2) \Gamma(1 - \Delta_1)}{\Gamma(\Delta_2) \Gamma(\Delta_1)} = 4\pi^2 \frac{\Gamma(i\lambda) \Gamma(-i\lambda)}{\Gamma(1 - i\lambda) \Gamma(1 + i\lambda)} = \frac{4\pi^2}{\lambda^2}
\end{align}
as desired.
Response to taking back the accepting of this answer
The idea that the above answer doesn't explain how to do the $d$-dimensional version of your integral is false. Equation (1) is most often derived in $d$ dimensions anyway because the Feynman parameter and conformal integral methods are not special to $d = 2$. So if we write
\begin{align}
\int \frac{d^d z}{|z - w_1|^{2\beta_1} |z - w_2|^{2\beta_2}} = \frac{\Gamma(\beta_1 + \beta_2 - d/2)}{\Gamma(d - \beta_1 - \beta_2)} \frac{\Gamma(d/2 - \beta_1) \Gamma(d/2 - \beta_2)}{\Gamma(\beta_1) \Gamma(\beta_2)} \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{|w_{12}|^{2\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 - d}} \quad (2)
\end{align}
we again see that the result is a delta function for $\Delta_1 + \Delta_2 = d$. This uses
\begin{equation}
d^dx = dx_1 \dots dx_d
\end{equation}
so $d\Re z d\Im z$ in $d = 2$. Now the exact same steps give
\begin{align}
\int d^dw I(w) &= \pi^{d/2} \lim_{x \to \infty} \int d^dz \frac{\Gamma(\Delta_2 + \alpha - d/2)}{\Gamma(d - \Delta_2 - \alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(d/2 - \Delta_2) \Gamma(d/2 - \alpha)}{\Gamma(\Delta_2) \Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{|x|^{2\alpha}}{|z|^{2\Delta_1} |x - z|^{2\Delta_2 + 2\alpha - d}} \\
&= \pi^d \frac{\Gamma(d/2 - \Delta_1) \Gamma(d/2 - \Delta_2)}{\Gamma(\Delta_1) \Gamma(\Delta_2)}
\end{align}

Thank you very much for the detailed answer, indeed I had not seen Eq. (1) before I will try and derive it on my own.

Disclaimer: The following is only an incomplete calculation/answer, but it may still serve as a first step.
By translation and rotational symmetry, OP's integral can only depend on the distance $|w|$, where $w:=w_1-w_2$. Let us use the convention that $d^2z=d{\rm Re}z~d{\rm Im}z.$ If we introduce a UV regulator $\epsilon>0$, OP's integral (1) becomes
$$ \begin{align}I(w)~=~&
\int_{\mathbb{C}}\!d^2z
\frac{1}{[|z-w_1|^2+\epsilon]^{\Delta_1}}
\frac{1}{[|z-w_2|^2+\epsilon]^{\Delta_2}}\cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{C}}\!d^2z
\frac{1}{[|z-w|^2+\epsilon]^{\Delta_1}}
\frac{1}{[|z|^2+\epsilon]^{\Delta_2}}\cr
~\stackrel{\text{Feyn.param.}}{=}~&\frac{1}{B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}
\int_{\mathbb{C}}\!d^2z\int_{[0,1]}\!dx
\frac{x^{\Delta_1-1}(1-x)^{\Delta_2-1}}{
[x|z-w|^2+(1-x)|z|^2+\epsilon]^{\Delta_1+\Delta_2}}\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}
\int_{\mathbb{C}}\!d^2z\int_{[0,1]}\!dx
\frac{x^{\Delta_1-1}(1-x)^{\Delta_2-1}}{
[|z|^2+x(1-x)|w|^2+\epsilon]^{\Delta_1+\Delta_2}}\cr
~\stackrel{\Delta_1+\Delta_2=2}{=}~&
\frac{\pi}{B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}\int_{[0,1]}\!dx
\frac{x^{\Delta_1-1}(1-x)^{\Delta_2-1}}{
x(1-x)|w|^2+\epsilon}\cr
~\stackrel{2x=1+y}{=}~&
\frac{\pi}{B(\Delta_1,\Delta_2)}
\int_{[-1,1]}\!\frac{dy}{2}
\frac{(1+y)^{\Delta_1-1}(1-y)^{\Delta_2-1}}{
(1-y^2)|w|^2/4+\epsilon}\cr
~\stackrel{\Delta_1=1+i\lambda}{=}~&
\frac{\pi}{B(1+i\lambda,1-i\lambda)}
\int_{[-1,1]}\!\frac{dy}{2}
\frac{\exp[2i\lambda {\rm artanh}(y)]}{
(1-y^2)|w|^2/4+\epsilon}\cr
~\stackrel{y=\tanh x}{=}~&
\frac{\sinh(\lambda\pi)}{\lambda}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\frac{dx}{2}
\frac{\exp[2i\lambda x]}{
|w|^2/4+\epsilon\cosh^2 x}\cr
~=~&\frac{2\sinh(\lambda\pi)}{\lambda}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dx
\frac{\exp[2i\lambda x]}{
|w|^2+4\epsilon\cosh^2 x}\cr
~\stackrel{x^{\prime}=2x}{=}~&
\frac{\sinh(\lambda\pi)}{\lambda}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dx
\frac{\exp[i\lambda x]}{
|w|^2+2\epsilon(1+\cosh x)}\cr
~\stackrel{\text{GR3.983.1}}{=}~&
\frac{\pi}{\epsilon\lambda}
\frac{\sin\left[\lambda {\rm arcosh}\left(
\frac{|w|^2}{2\epsilon}+1\right)\right]}{
\sqrt{\left(\frac{|w|^2}{2\epsilon}+1\right)^2-1}}.
\end{align}$$

Ideas: Introduce point-splitting $i\epsilon$ regularization for the $w$'s. Maybe impose $\rm Im$ cf. Sokhotski-Plemelj thm? Notes for later: Symanzik star formula: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02824349 https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0006098 App. B. Split (B.3.b) in diag & off-diag. Uses Cheng-Wu theorem. https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2407 App. 12. https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1504 eq. (B.1). https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4845 eq. (36). https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.07543 App. B. https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07295 eq. (5).

Notes for later: https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.07543 eq. (3.7). Fourier transform: Euclidean signature: $\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}!d^dx~(x^2)^{\alpha}e^{-ip\cdot x}$ $=\frac{1}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!\frac{dt}{t}t^{-\alpha}\int{\mathbb{R}^d}!d^dx~e^{-t x^2-ip\cdot x}$ $=\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!\frac{dt}{t}t^{-\alpha-d/2}~e^{-p^2/4t}$ $=\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}\int{\mathbb{R}_+}!\frac{du}{u}u^{\alpha+d/2}~e^{-up^2/4}$ $=\pi^{d/2}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+d/2)}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}\left(\frac{4}{p^2}\right)^{\alpha+d/2}$.

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0006098 App. B.$\quad I_n(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}!\frac{d^dy}{\pi^{d/2}}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\Gamma(\delta_i)}{(y-x_i)^{2\delta_i}}$ $=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}!\frac{d^dy}{\pi^{d/2}}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n\Gamma(\delta_i)\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!d\lambda_i~\lambda_i^{\delta_i-1}\right]e^{-S}$ $=\left[\prod{i=1}^n\Gamma(\delta_i)\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!d\lambda_i~\lambda_i^{\delta_i-1}\right]\Lambda^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{1}{\Lambda}\sum{j<k}\lambda_j\lambda_kr_{jk}}$, $\quad\Delta:=\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_i=d$.

$\quad S=\sum_i\lambda_i(y-x_i)^2$. $\quad S-\Lambda(y-\frac{1}{\Lambda}\sum_i\lambda_i x_i)^2=\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2-\frac{1}{\Lambda}(\sum_i\lambda_ix_i)^2$ $=\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2+\frac{1}{2\Lambda}\sum_{i,j}\lambda_i\lambda_j{ (x_i-x_j)^2-x_i^2-x_j^2}$ $=\frac{1}{\Lambda}\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_jr_{ij}$. $\quad r_{ij}=(x_i-x_j)^2$. $\quad e^{-z}=\oint_{\mathbb{R}-}!\frac{ds}{2\pi i}\Gamma(s)z^{-s}$. $\quad e^{-z}=-\oint{\mathbb{R}+}!\frac{ds}{2\pi i}\Gamma(-s)z^s$ $=\int{i\mathbb{R}+c}!\frac{ds}{2\pi i}\Gamma(-s)z^s$.

$J_n=\left[\prod_{i=1}^n\Gamma(\delta_i)\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!\frac{d\lambda_i}{\Lambda{\mu}^{\delta_i/2}}\lambda_i^{\delta_i-1}\right]e^{-\frac{1}{\Lambda_{\mu}}\sum_{j<k}\lambda_j\lambda_kr_{jk}}$ $=\left[\prod_{i=1}^n\Gamma(\delta_i)\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!\frac{d\lambda_i}{\Lambda{\mu}^{\delta_i/2}}\lambda_i^{\delta_i-1}\right]\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!d\sigma~\delta(\sigma-\Lambda{\kappa})e^{-\frac{1}{\Lambda_{\mu}}\sum_{j<k}\lambda_j\lambda_kr_{jk}}$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!\frac{d\sigma}{\sigma}\left[\prod{i=1}^n\Gamma(\delta_i)\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!\frac{d\alpha_i}{A{\mu}^{\delta_i/2}}\alpha_i^{\delta_i-1}\sigma^{\delta_i/2}\right]\delta(1-A_{\kappa})e^{-\frac{\sigma}{A_{\mu}}\sum_{j<k}\alpha_j\alpha_kr_{jk}}$ $=\Gamma(\frac{\Delta}{2})\left[\prod_{i=1}^n\Gamma(\delta_i)\int_{\mathbb{R}+}!d\alpha_i~\alpha_i^{\delta_i-1}\right]\delta(1-A{\kappa})\left(\sum_{j<k}\alpha_j\alpha_kr_{jk}\right)^{-\Delta/2}$.
